# How to dynamically add an arbitrary number of values to a specific level in a pandas multiindex using python?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have this `dataframe` with a `MultiIndex` object as its `index`.

```
                                         apple
level_1 level_2 level_3 level_4 level_5
bga     B       G       1       0          5.0
```

How can I dynamically add a random amount of values to level 5?

I have this:

```
randData = ["r1", "r13", "r14", "r6"]
for x in randData:
    df.loc[( "bga", "B", "G", "1", x ), "apple"] = np.random.randn(1)[0]
```

Which works great but for lists larger than 4 items takes forever. I was thinking of a simple slice of something like this:

```
df.loc[( "bga", "B", "G", "1" ), "apple"] = (randData, np.random.randn(4))
```

But it doesn't like that (which makes sense) and I can't think of any other way to slice it that would allow me to add values to the level.

I have thought of simply recreating the `MultiIndex` and setting the new index, but thats a bit more work than I was looking for with the slicing option.

Does anyone else have any thoughts? TIA!

Comment: Do not edit "solved" into titles. The only correct way to mark a question solved is to click the checkbox by an answer; that alone is sufficient -- solved questions have different color/highlighting/formatting cues on the main page so they're easily distinguishable. See [Is it OK to add SOLVED to the title of a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116101/is-it-ok-to-add-solved-to-the-title-of-a-question) on [meta.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MultiIndex seems to be slowing you down. Internally we are to think of these as tuples (I believe). Since here you want to do some parallelisation I would suggest to `.reset_index` so the levels become columns. Then you can fuss around there.

I have used the `pd.concat` which fills with `NaN` those entries which we do not specify. Then can use the `fillna` with `ffill` to copy down the entries from above.

Code:

```
x = pd.DataFrame({'apple': 5.0}, index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([( "bga", "B", "G", 1, 0)]))
print(x)

y = x.reset_index()
print(y)

z = pd.DataFrame({'level_4': ['r1', 'r13', 'r14', 'r16'], 'apple': np.random.randn(4)})
print(z)

w = pd.concat([y, z])
print(w)

u = w.fillna(method='ffill')
print(u)

v = u.set_index(['level_0', 'level_1', 'level_2', 'level_3', 'level_4'])
print(v)
```

Output:

```
             apple
bga B G 1 0    5.0
  level_0 level_1 level_2  level_3  level_4  apple
0     bga       B       G        1        0    5.0
  level_4     apple
0      r1  0.286195
1     r13 -0.039496
2     r14 -0.571542
3     r16  1.196218
  level_0 level_1 level_2  level_3 level_4     apple
0     bga       B       G      1.0       0  5.000000
0     NaN     NaN     NaN      NaN      r1  0.286195
1     NaN     NaN     NaN      NaN     r13 -0.039496
2     NaN     NaN     NaN      NaN     r14 -0.571542
3     NaN     NaN     NaN      NaN     r16  1.196218
  level_0 level_1 level_2  level_3 level_4     apple
0     bga       B       G      1.0       0  5.000000
0     bga       B       G      1.0      r1  0.286195
1     bga       B       G      1.0     r13 -0.039496
2     bga       B       G      1.0     r14 -0.571542
3     bga       B       G      1.0     r16  1.196218
                                            apple
level_0 level_1 level_2 level_3 level_4          
bga     B       G       1.0     0        5.000000
                                r1       0.286195
                                r13     -0.039496
                                r14     -0.571542
                                r16      1.196218
```

Edit: timing comparison:

[image: timings, 100X faster my way]

Comment: I see. I was trying to stay in MultiIndex, but I see how this makes more sense and is much easier to work with. I will give this a try tomorrow! Thanks!

Comment: Hey, your solution worked great. Thanks again! Guess in the future I'll just use long format then translate afterwards. Seems logical